# sbt downloading 2.13.5 scala-library though the Scala version specified is 2.12.15

Tags: scala, sbt

We are using the following:

1. SBT Version :  1.5.5
2. Scala Version  : 2.12.15

To publish the artifacts to maven , we are using the https://github.com/sbt/sbt-maven-resolver
plugin.

As soon as i add, the plugin the 2.13.5 scala library gets downloaded and makes the code incompatible.
like the following errors :

All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[error] Test com.mycomosi.bdp.common.lambda.AvroToJsonTest.transformation failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.JavaConverters$.asScalaB
ufferConverter(Ljava/util/List;)Lscala/collection/convert/Decorators$AsScala;, took 0.554 sec

Any help is highly appreciated !

```
import sbt.Keys.libraryDependencies
import sbt.{Credentials, Path}
import sbt.ThisBuild

import scala.language.postfixOps


ThisBuild / version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.mycomosi.bdp"
ThisBuild / description := "Big Data Producer"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.15"
ThisBuild / scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
ThisBuild / publishMavenStyle := true
ThisBuild / publishTo := Some("bdp artifact repo" at "https://mycom-osi-066505437618.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/maven/bda/")
ThisBuild / credentials += Credentials(
  "mycom-osi/bda",
  "mycom-osi-066505437618.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  "aws",
  sys.env.getOrElse("CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN",""))


//FIXME ... kind of conflict with Avro generator
//ThisBuild / javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.11", "-target", "1.11")

//TODO Upgrade to JUNIT5

//FIXME DeepIntegrationTest add the project test scope to the IT (Integration Test) scope ... but it breaks the scope of dependsOn for IT ... huge pain in the ass to solve that one
lazy val DeepIntegrationTest = IntegrationTest.extend(Test)

lazy val versions = new {
  val slf4j = "1.7.32"

  //TODO Upgrade to 3.2.10 (import impacts)
  val scalaTest = "3.0.8"
  //val flink = "1.14.0"
  val flink = "1.13.3"
  val avro = "1.10.2"
  val fasterxml = "2.12.3"

  val parquetAvro = "1.12.2"
  val hadoop = "3.1.4"

  //lambda
  val xray = "2.9.1"
  val awsSdk = "2.17.103"

  val schemaRegistry = "1.1.5"

  val akkaStream = "2.6.17"
  val akkaStreamAlp = "3.0.3"
}

//FIXME: Update log4j-core deps
lazy val logDeps = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.4",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % versions.slf4j,
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % versions.slf4j
  //  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.14.1",
  //  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.14.1"
)

//noinspection SbtDependencyVersionInspection
//Version 1.0.2 is incompatible with akka stream
lazy val scalaJava8Compat = "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.8.0"

//noinspection SbtDependencyVersionInspection
lazy val commonDeps = Seq(
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "regions" % versions.awsSdk % Test,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "sts" % versions.awsSdk % Test,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "http-client-spi" % versions.awsSdk,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "apache-client" % versions.awsSdk,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "aws-crt-client" % s"${versions.awsSdk}-PREVIEW",
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "sdk-core" % versions.awsSdk,
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "utils" % versions.awsSdk excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.reactivestreams "),ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),ExclusionRule(organization = "software.amazon.awssdk")),
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "auth" % versions.awsSdk excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "software.amazon.awssdk"),ExclusionRule(organization = "software.amazon.eventstream")),
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "cloudformation" % versions.awsSdk
) ++ jacksonScala



lazy val junit = "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11"

lazy val testDeps = Seq(
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "sso" % versions.awsSdk % "it,test",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-tests" % "1.1.0" % "it,test",
  "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter-core" % "0.19" % "it,test",
  //FIXME Test scope ?
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % versions.scalaTest,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % versions.scalaTest % "it,test",
  junit % "it,test",
  "org.awaitility" % "awaitility-scala" % "4.1.0" % "it,test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.11.0" % Test)

lazy val avroDep = "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % versions.avro

//noinspection SbtDependencyVersionInspection
lazy val jacksonAvro = "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-avro" % versions.fasterxml
lazy val jacksonScala = Seq("com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % versions.fasterxml)

lazy val serDeDeps = Seq(
  "software.amazon.glue" % "schema-registry-serde" % versions.schemaRegistry excludeAll(
    //Allow to reduce the artifact size by 21 MB
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.kafka"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.kjetland"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.github.erosb")),
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "glue" % versions.awsSdk) ++ parquetAvroDeps.map(_ % Test) :+ avroDep :+ jacksonAvro

lazy val kdsSdkDeps = "software.amazon.awssdk" % "kinesis" % versions.awsSdk

//noinspection SbtDependencyVersionInspection
lazy val ssmClientDeps = "software.amazon.awssdk" % "ssm" % versions.awsSdk

//noinspection SbtDependencyVersionInspection
lazy val sqsClientDeps = "software.amazon.awssdk" % "sqs" % versions.awsSdk

lazy val kplDeps = "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-producer" % "0.14.9"

lazy val kclDeps = "software.amazon.kinesis" % "amazon-kinesis-client" % "2.3.6"

//Dependencies for Lambda transformer
lazy val lambdaDeps = Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.1",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "3.10.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-log4j2" % "1.2.0"
  //"com.amazonaws" % "aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core" % versions.xray
)

lazy val lambdaTestDeps = Seq()

//noinspection SbtDependencyVersionInspection
//Dependencies for KDA transformer
lazy val kdaDeps = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % versions.flink % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % versions.flink % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % versions.flink % "provided",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime" % "1.2.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-kinesisanalytics-flink" % "2.0.0",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "30.0-jre",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kinesis" % versions.flink,
  "software.amazon.glue" % "schema-registry-flink-serde" % "1.1.5",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-avro" % versions.flink,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-parquet" % versions.flink,

  //"org.apache.flink" % "flink-s3-fs-hadoop" % versions.flink % IntegrationTest,
  //flink-s3-fs-hadoop dependency is already available as a plugin on KDA side (according to AWS support) (so removing it from the main scope)
  //Removing it also from the IntegrationTest scope since it fails all the Its with:
  //Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair
  //    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:254)
  //    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:328)
  //    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:127)

  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % versions.flink % "it,test",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-test-utils" % versions.flink % "it,test" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"))
  //cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20859
)

lazy val parquetAvroDeps = Seq(
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % versions.parquetAvro,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % versions.hadoop excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % versions.hadoop intransitive()
)

lazy val global = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Big Data Producer",
    settings
  )
  .disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .aggregate(
    common
  )
```

and the plugin is added in  project/plugin.sbt

Comment: can you share how your build.sbt looks like and also how you are trying to add the plugin?

Comment: Note that this plugin won't help for publishing to a repository like you seem to want to do.

Comment: as requested added a parital build.sbt

Comment: @gael can u please recommend anything else..